# add default content to custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to add the default data set to a custom taxonomy called 'foods'. The default data sets are;

- vegetarian
- salad
- carrot
- nonvegetarian
- chicken
- mutton

I have already created the taxonomy called foods, but I am unable to add the default data to it. Please help. I really don't understand how to use wp_insert_term() in the WordPress codex.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples in which you must customize to your theme and usage.
Step 1 would be creating your term with [wp_insert_term()](http://bit.ly/njBFSj). It must be used with a hook called 'init' like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'your_function' );
your_function(){
$parent_term = term_exists( 'fruits', 'product' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
wp_insert_term(
  'Apple', // the term 
  'product', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'A yummy apple.',
    'slug' => 'apple',
    'parent'=> $parent_term_id
  )
);
```

}

I register my custom taxo's with my custom post type (within the same file)
Here is a custom taxonomy example from my notes:

```
register_taxonomy( 'custom_tag', 
    array('review_type'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => false,    /* if this is false, it acts like tags */                
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Tags', 'yourtheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Tag', 'yourtheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Custom Tags', 'yourtheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Custom Tags', 'yourtheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Custom Tag', 'yourtheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Custom Tag:', 'yourtheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Custom Tag', 'yourtheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Custom Tag', 'yourtheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Tag', 'yourtheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Custom Tag Name', 'yourtheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer would be great if could let me know how to add vegetarian as a parent and salad and carrot as a child of the vegetarian please.

Comment: I've never done exactly that, but the tools are there within that custom taxonomy snippet. register_taxonomy has parent_item arguments. You may need to research more on what those mean and how to use them if they do not work "out of the box".